# Modeling multiple associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm trying to capture a data hierarchy in a rails model and am having some trouble. here is a releationship diagram: https://www.lucidchart.com/invitations/accept/5744614c-2054-4f79-a842-8118e985f840

My models are User, Recipe, RecipeIngredient, Ingredient, and Unit.

- Users own Recipes. A User can have zero to many Recipes.
- Recipes have zero to many RecipeIngredients. RecipeIngredients are
  dependents of Recipes.
- A RecipeIngredient points to exactly one Recipe and one Ingredient
  and one Unit.
- Neither Unit nor Ingredient are dependents of RecipeIngredient.
- Ingredients can be used in multiple RecipeIngredients.
- Units can be used in multiple RecipeIngredients.

Here are my model definitions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    accepts_nested_attributes_for   :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

I've used this in my EDIT form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |recipe_ingredient| %>
    <%= recipe_ingredient.collection_select( :ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name ) %>
    <%= recipe_ingredient.number_field :quantity, :step => 'any' %>
    <%= recipe_ingredient.collection_select( :unit, Unit.all, :name, :name ) %>
    <%= recipe_ingredient.text_field :comment %>
```

When I submit the form, the Recipe is updated properly, but new RecipeIngredient rows are created (rather than updated). The Ingredient is nil in all of the new rows. I've obviously overlooked an association definition. What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you closer to what you are looking for:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for   :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

This of course assumes that you've set up all the models with the correct fields/indexes. `Recipe` needs to have a `user_id` field, `RecipeIngredient` needs to have `recipe_id, ingredient_id, unit_id` fields.

I've never built a 4-way join table (just the usual 3-way, i.e. User, Office, and Appointment models where an Appointment belongs_to a User and an Office). But this should work, at least with a little modification. Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the Ingredients need to be referenced in the Recipe? My thought was Recipe has-a RecipeIngredient and RecipeIngredient has-a Ingredient. I don't understand why it is necessary for the Recipe Model to know about the relations of its dependents. Can you help me understand?

Comment: Sure, I would imagine that you want to be able to retrieve a list of all of the `Ingredients` under a  `Recipe`, that way you could do something like `@recipe.ingredients`. It needs to reference `RecipeIngredient` as that is the 'joining table' that connects the three models.

Comment: You might want to actually change the nesting to make it simpler and have it as: `User` has_many `Recipes`, `Recipes` has_many `Ingredients`, `Ingredients` has_one `Unit`.

Comment: The problem with the simplified nesting is that Ingredients are shared across recipes; such as "eggs". Many recipes may include eggs. RecipeIngredients has the number of eggs and special comments (like "separated"). Units can vary across recipes as well. One recipe may have a tsp of salt. Another may have a cup of salt. Same Ingredient, different units and quantities.